# Resume/continue interrupted evaluation

Tags: evaluation, interruption

I interrupted an evaluation to quickly do something else. How do I resume the interrupted evaluation? I cannot open the "Interrupt evaluation" window, as it is disabled. There is no "Resume" button to press...

Comment: Does pressing F5 work?

Comment: Yes, F5 also does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: too voting to close this question as off-topic because h   I

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- It seems you have to evaluate `Return[]`. Strange that there is no command-button for this action.
- <kbd>F5</kbd> also works.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Dialogs.html

Comment: As of 2020, in MMA 11.0.1 resumption remains obscure and dialog help link is broken. F5 does indeed still work though, but finding this out is also a matter of luck as I only found this question after writing a (longer, more detailed) duplicate having somehow failed to find this Q by searching...